# Creating a simple bash script that uses cat and has 3 arguments

Tags: linux, bash

I have this bash command I am using to cat the output of two java programs that take 1 parameter each into a file:

```
cat file.ext | java program1 argument1 | java program2 argument2 > argument3
```

argument3 is a optional and if it is not provided it should just be file.srtd

How can I create a bash script for this?

Comment: where is `argument2`?

Comment: Mistake in question :)

Comment: This question doesn't convey clearly what you wish to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In bash, the variable `$n` is the `n`<sup>th</sup> argument.  The variable `$#` is the number of arguments given by the user.

So you can do something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

arg3=$3
if (( $# < 3 )) ; then
    arg3="file.srtd"
fi;

cat file.ext | java program1 $1 | java program2 $2 > $arg3
```

You can look at [shell parameters](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameters) and [shell parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) for more information.

Comment: You can't assign to `$3` with `$3=`.

Comment: The `if` is redundant here, you could do `(( $# < 3 )) && arg3="file.srtd"`

Comment: @mona_sax Seriously, **redundant**? Not anything with a shortcut available is reduntant.

Comment: @OhadEytan : Hmm, forgive me if it is wrong terminology, I personally I would go with a more idiomatic  `(( $# < 3 )) && arg3="file.srtd"`as it clearly conveys the idea and save you a few lines in typing.

Comment: @mona_sax no hard feelings :)

Comment: Note that the idiomatic code would avoid the assignments and `if` statement altogether and use `"${3:-file.sttd}"` directly in the redirection on the `java` command, as in [Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38695202/15168).  An assignment would be sensible if you referred to the name more than once: `arg3="${3:-file.srtd}"` and then use `"$arg3"` where needed.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify a default value for a variable if it's not set with the syntax `${var:-default}`.

```
java program1 "$1" < file.ext | java program2 "$2" > "${3:-file.srtd}"
```

You should also remember to quote the variables in case they contain special characters.

Answer (score 0):

You could do :

```
file="$3"
[ -z "$file" ] && file="file.srtd"
#then use `file` for the rest of the program.
```

Comment: The output of `program1` is supposed to be piped to `program2`.